# Ubuntu download and upload speed drasitcally drop after a few hours

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, hardware

I have a strange issue. My computer is using gigabit connection and after booting, the download and upload speeds are very good (download: 800 Mbit/s, upload 600 Mbit/s). After a few hours, it drastically drops to around 10 Mbit/s for each. I have searched online and nothing seemed to help. The pc is pretty old, so I wouldn't rule out a hardware issue, but it is not the cable or an ip conflict, as I have changed the location of the pc and the problem persists.

ifconfig -a output:

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:99:a3:72:fc
      inet addr:192.168.1.109  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::219:99ff:fea3:72fc/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1250278 errors:0 dropped:942 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:519434 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:1735192455 (1.7 GB)  TX bytes:619548103 (619.5 MB)
      Interrupt:17 Memory:c0020000-c0040000
```

lspci -knn | grep -iA2 net output:

```
Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10ef] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Fujitsu Technology Solutions 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection [1734:11a6]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Could it be a network adapter issue or is it more likely something related to the operating system?

Operating system: Ubuntu Server 16.04

Edit: the connection seems to drop every few minutes or so. I checked every 5-10 minutes and the download and upload seem to halve themselves.

Comment: It's most likely your ISP or the site you're accessing. Do you have the same issue with different sites? Are all sites affected in the same way? If you download from two different sites in parallel, do they each drop to 5Mb/s or 10Mb/s? If you use your computer with another Internet connection or another computer on your Internet connection, do you have the same issue?

Comment: Hello, I have another pc on the same network and this problem has never occured there, so I am ruling out ISP issues or website issues.

Comment: Cached by your ISP, downloading their popular files will be fast, getting others from the originals might be slow...